# Struts 1 Nested tags: getting unexpected html

Tags: struts, struts-1

I am working on an old application using Struts 1. We are using nested tags. For below code:

```xml
 <nested:form action="/save.do?method=save">
     <h2>Indexed Property Example</h2>

      <nested:iterate property="lines" indexId="idx">
         Name: <nested:text property="name"  indexed="true"/>
         Town: <nested:text property="town" indexed="true"/>
            <nested:iterate property="inches" indexId="j">
                Inch: <nested:text  property="length" indexed="true"></nested:text>
            </nested:iterate>   
      </nested:iterate>
   <nested:submit value="save" />
</nested:form>
```

I am getting below html:

```xml
     <h2>Indexed Property Example</h2>


         Name: <input name="nestedForm[0].lines[0].name" value="" type="text">
         Town: <input name="nestedForm[0].lines[0].town" value="" type="text">

                Inch: <input name="nestedForm[0].lines[0].inches[0].length" value="0" type="text">

                Inch: <input name="nestedForm[1].lines[0].inches[1].length" value="0" type="text">


   <input name="" value="save" type="submit">
```

If you see in second Inch label we have nestedForm[1] it should be 0. I have to change to this data and submit back to server. If I change it directly in html struts populate all objects automatically. Can anyone suggest me if I am doing anything wrong here.